# Solve a Cauchy integral if the singular node is an endpoint?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I have one definite integral that needs to be evaluated from -1 to 1 in the Cauchy principal value sense. Math programs only let me put the singular points between the integration limits , but my singular point is -1.

The integral is complex,it has a strong singularity on -1, but how can I integrate from -1 to 1?

Here is the function for simple copy and paste:

```
-(((1 - xi)*xi*Sqrt[(0.056249999999999994*(1 - xi) + 0.10625000000000001*xi - 0.049999999999999996*(1 + xi))^2]*
    (0. + ((0.056249999999999994*(1 - xi) + 0.10625000000000001*xi - 0.049999999999999996*(1 + xi))*(-0.1 - 0.05*(1 - xi)*xi + 0.10625*(1 - xi)*(1 + xi) + 0.05625*xi*(1 + xi))*
       (1.3 + 4*(BesselK[0, 628.318530717959*Sqrt[0. + (-0.1 - 0.05*(1 - xi)*xi + 0.10625*(1 - xi)*(1 + xi) + 0.05625*xi*(1 + xi))^2]] + 
          (0.003183098861837905*(-(0.0015915494309189525/Sqrt[0. + (-0.1 - 0.05*(1 - xi)*xi + 0.10625*(1 - xi)*(1 + xi) + 0.05625*xi*(1 + xi))^2]) + 
             BesselK[1, 628.318530717959*Sqrt[0. + (-0.1 - 0.05*(1 - xi)*xi + 0.10625*(1 - xi)*(1 + xi) + 0.05625*xi*(1 + xi))^2]]))/
           Sqrt[0. + (-0.1 - 0.05*(1 - xi)*xi + 0.10625*(1 - xi)*(1 + xi) + 0.05625*xi*(1 + xi))^2])))/(Sqrt[(0.056249999999999994*(1 - xi)
+ 0.10625000000000001*xi - 0.049999999999999996*(1 + xi))^2]*
       Sqrt[0. + (-0.1 - 0.05*(1 - xi)*xi + 0.10625*(1 - xi)*(1 + xi) + 0.05625*xi*(1 + xi))^2]) + (0.*(-0.1 - 0.05*(1 - xi)*xi + 0.10625*(1 - xi)*(1 + xi) + 0.05625*xi*(1 + xi))*
       (0.7 + 1256.637061435918*Sqrt[0. + (-0.1 - 0.05*(1 - xi)*xi + 0.10625*(1 - xi)*(1 + xi) + 0.05625*xi*(1 + xi))^2]*
         BesselK[1, 628.318530717959*Sqrt[0. + (-0.1 - 0.05*(1 - xi)*xi + 0.10625*(1 - xi)*(1 + xi) + 0.05625*xi*(1 + xi))^2]] + 
        8*(BesselK[0, 628.318530717959*Sqrt[0. + (-0.1 - 0.05*(1 - xi)*xi + 0.10625*(1 - xi)*(1 + xi) + 0.05625*xi*(1 + xi))^2]] + 
          (0.003183098861837905*(-(0.0015915494309189525/Sqrt[0. + (-0.1 - 0.05*(1 - xi)*xi + 0.10625*(1 - xi)*(1 + xi) + 0.05625*xi*(1 + xi))^2]) + 
             BesselK[1, 628.318530717959*Sqrt[0. + (-0.1 - 0.05*(1 - xi)*xi + 0.10625*(1 - xi)*(1 + xi) + 0.05625*xi*(1 + xi))^2]]))/
           Sqrt[0. + (-0.1 - 0.05*(1 - xi)*xi + 0.10625*(1 - xi)*(1 + xi) + 0.05625*xi*(1 + xi))^2])))/(Sqrt[(0.056249999999999994*(1 - xi)
+ 0.10625000000000001*xi - 0.049999999999999996*(1 + xi))^2]*
       Sqrt[0. + (-0.1 - 0.05*(1 - xi)*xi + 0.10625*(1 - xi)*(1 + xi) + 0.05625*xi*(1 + xi))^2])))/(8*Pi*Sqrt[0. + (-0.1 - 0.05*(1 - xi)*xi + 0.10625*(1 - xi)*(1 + xi) + 0.05625*xi*(1 + xi))^2]))
```

Could mathematica solve this integral since the singular point is on the endpoint of the integration?

Does anyone have a hint on how to solve the above integral ?

Comment: Is $x=1$ the only singularity in the $[-1,1]$ range? Which kind of singularity is it?

Comment: To figure out what the kind of singularity you have you can series expand it about $x=-1$. Your input looks like Matehematica so you can try `Series[ f[x], {x, -1, order}]`  (order = 1 should be enough). Mathematica can also do  Principal value integrals (though only analytically if I remember correctly): `Integrate[f(x), {x, -1, 1}, PrincipalValue -> True]`

Comment: Thanks everybody for the replys, It is a strong singularity of type (1/r) , no adaptivity technique seems to be working, and cauchy could only be evaluated if the singular point is in the interval . I tried to solve it analytically like Winther asked and got the input back! This integral is getting on my nerves !

Comment: One thing you can try is to series expand it about the singular point to get the term $\frac{C}{x-x_0}$. Then you can subtract this term from the function (which should make it finite at $x=x_0$ if it's just a simple pole here). Then the principal value of the integral is the integral of this function + the principal value of $\frac{C}{x-x_0}$ (which should be $0$). I don't know if this is numerically stable though.

Comment: Thanks Winther, I tried the subtraction of singularity technique and got the answer around PrincipalValue = 0.1, but god knows if it is correct, I was hoping another technique would prove or get another result

Comment: If anyone could give it a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several studies I have found that for a endpoint singularity this integral has no finite answer and when used on a numerical program its value should be set to 0.